# Parsing data into 3 different 2-D arrays using function

Tags: c

I'm trying to understand a line of code and how it is parsing so that I can organize the array appropriately.

So I have a 1D buffer of size 78 (GPriors). I'm trying to put it into 3 different arrays of size 13X2. My questions is about the line of code:

```
GPriors + (i * newGMMClassify->nStates)
```

that is in the argument of InitGMM. It seems to be adding an integer to an array, which doesn't make sense to me. Is it affecting the index?

```
for(i=0;i<inClass;i++)
{    
    InitGMM(newGMMClassify->G[i],GPriors + (i * newGMMClassify->nStates));
}

void InitGMM(Gmm* gmm, float *inMu)
{
    for(i = 0; i < gmm->States; i++) 
    {
        for (j = 0; j < gmm->FeatLen; j++) 
        {
        gmm->Mu[i][j] = inMu[(i*gmm->FeatLen) + j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is equivalent to `&GPriors[i * newGMMClassify->nStates]`.  It gives the address of an element of the `GPriors` array to the function `InitGMM()`.

Comment: `InitGMM()` does not refer to `inprior` at all.

Comment: Sorry. I cut out some stuff to post here, and I did it incorrectly. I'll update it.

Answer (score 1):

`GPriors` is pointer. In pointer arithmetic (you can learn more here [Pointer Arithmetic](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html) ) when you add an integer to a pointer, for example
`GPriors + 2` the result will be a pointer too which points to address `&GPriors + 2*sizeof(GPriors)`.

If you apply the same to your line of code you will get a pointer to address `&GPriors + ((i * newGMMClassify->nStates))*sizeof(GPriors)`.

This pointer then passed into `InitGMM` function.